# heatmap in d3js has weird x axis

Tags: d3.js, heatmap

I have changed this code https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/df39c69d1d0cb1b71429b2cd47e2a189
according to my need. But the x-axis has on first and last position empty line. How can I get rid of it?

I tried to play with xScale but no success. [my heatmap result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHUMf.png)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4):

To remove those ticks just do:

```
axis.tickSizeOuter(0);
```

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis), `tickSizeOuter()`:

> ...controls the length of the square ends of the domain path, offset from the native position of the axis. Thus, the “outer ticks” are not actually ticks but part of the domain path, and their position is determined by the associated scale’s domain extent [...] An outer tick size of 0 suppresses the square ends of the domain path, instead producing a straight line.

Here is the bl.ocks you linked with that change: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/a5153b4a293d72325c1aaee0b9aaac0c/52d701ca5d5a79809316eef39eafa2ccfc70879b

Comment: Definitely the right way to do it, sorry I missed this!